# How to change character set of the XMLTYPE variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob, xmltype

I'm currently having non-utf-8 DB but I need to produce XMLType variable with utf-8 encoding. I'm having a workaround but there seems to be bug in the Oracle, see the following link: 
 https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10238641

...and Oracle Support bug: 7698684

The bug causes random

```
ORA-1482: unsupported character set
ORA-6512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 107
```

First of all I'm getting XMLType with dbms_xmlgen package. That XMLType is encoded with DB character set.

To convert it to utf-8 character set I do like this:

- I convert XMLType variable to BLOB variable with getBlobVal method using NLS_CHARSET_ID
  ('UTF8') as parameter
- I convert BLOB variable back to XMLType with XMLType constructor method using BLOB variable as first parameter and NLS_CHARSET_ID
  ('UTF8') as second parameter. **This causes random error :(**

Does anybody know any alternative solution for this?

```
  l_xml   := dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType(l_ctx);
  l_xml_b := l_xml.getBlobVal(C_UTF8_CHARSET_ID);
  l_xml   := XMLType(l_xml_b, C_UTF8_CHARSET_ID);
```

Comment: Where have you found the definition for [`XMLType.getBlobVal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/t_xml.htm#i1010715)? in the documentation it is not listed as having a parameter

Comment: At least it's written here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm

Comment: It seems to be undocumented (probably documentation bug) but you're right it works. What version are you running?

Comment: By the way I won't write an answer right now since I don't have time to find references, but I'm pretty sure an XMLType is abstract and **doesn't have a character set** (like a DATE doesn't have a format). The character set is choosen when you transform the XMLType into readable/exportable format.

Comment: 11g R2 (not remember detailed version but can check tomorrow). XMLType keeps own character set information. I'm quite absolutely sure about it because I'm returning that XMLType variable throught 11g native web services and if I do my utf-8 encode stuff then it really exposes web service with utf-8! Otherwise it just returns xml via web service encoded with the DB character set.

Comment: XMLType is the only way to expose data larger than varchar2 max lenght with 11g native web services. If I use CLOB Oracle will implicitly convert it to varchar2 :)

Comment: Sorry, the DB is not R2 it's 11.1.0.7.0

Comment: XMLType constructor with BFILE seems to work (character set id as second parameter)! However I don't want to write code that writes xml to the disk and reads it back to xmltype. Too much overhead I think.

Comment: You're right again, I checked in two DBs with different character sets and the same XMLType had different encodings. You can't use CLOB of VARCHAR2 to export an XMLType because both datatypes will have the character set of the DB. Why don't you use BLOB? `l_xml.getBlobVal(C_UTF8_CHARSET_ID)` has the right character set and header information.

Comment: BLOB cannot be exposed with web services. I think I have to encode characters to Base64 format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with convert function. It was not possible to convert the whole xml document (even the clob value of it) but only element values.

This was not working (XMLType constructor fails):

```
l_xml := XMLType(convert(l_xml.getClobVal, 'UTF8'));
```

So I had to put convert to the query string (this is just an example):

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType(
  q'{select convert('ä', 'UTF8') myValue from dual}')
from dual
```

Finally I made a function which reads dictionary and loops through all columns of the given table/view and generates select statement string where all columns are converted separately to UTF8. This string can then be passed as parameter to the dbms_xmlgen.newContext function.